# Generic Repository within DDD: How can I make this interface generic?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

I'm developing a multi-module CMS application following Domain-Driven Design principles. I'm trying to figure out how to implement Generic Repository, thus avoiding a lot of boiler-plate code.

The idea is to have a "two-way" mapping strategy (model to entity and vice versa) and Generic Repository implemented in the Persistence module. Further, an interface in the Domain module would act as a contract between Domain and Persistence, so I can use it for later injection in the other layers.

How can I make this interface generic?

To be specific, the problem here is the mapping. Since I'm using a "two-way" mapping strategy, the Domain module has no idea about DB specific entities.

Is there a way to map generic type models between layers? Or use some other mapping strategy while keeping the layers loosely coupled?

Here is a code example to clarify what I'm trying to achieve.
This would be the code example for Generic Repository:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractJpaMappedType {
  …
  String attribute
}

@Entity
public class ConcreteJpaType extends AbstractJpaMappedType { … }

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface JpaMappedTypeRepository<T extends AbstractJpaMappedType>
  extends Repository<T, Long> {

  @Query("select t from #{#entityName} t where t.attribute = ?1")
  List<T> findAllByAttribute(String attribute);
}

public interface ConcreteRepository
  extends JpaMappedTypeRepository<ConcreteType> { … }
```

Further, I want to make my own Custom Repository to be able to do some mapping of model to entity and vice versa, so I wouldn't have JPA specific annotation in my domain classes, thus making it loosely coupled. I want this Custom Repository to implement an interface from Domain module, allowing me to inject it later in the Services layer.

```
public class CustomRepositoryImpl implements CustomRepository {

    public final JpaMappedTypeRepository<T> repository;
    ...
}
```

How can I make this class and this interface generic so that I would be able to do mapping between model and entity, since Domain layer has no information about entity classes?

Comment: I think we're going to need to see some code you have written.  It's not clear to me what "interface" you need to be "generic."

Comment: Also, can you be a little clearer about what your goals are?  Two-way mapping suggests domain ignorance in both directions, and there's really no such thing as operating a repository, generic or not, without conferring any domain knowledge at all (at the very least, you would have knowledge of the domain entity you want to retrieve). If you really think you need that kind of two-way decoupling, you also need a good reason for doing it.  So tell us your reasoning.

Comment: Otherwise, the obvious answer is to just pass strings around.  Strings are completely agnostic; it would be up to the receiving end to decode them.  There *are* legitimate use cases for that.

Comment: Why is there a need to have this "two-way" mapping? The repository layer is meant to translate the model to an entity to be able to use ORM and interact with the database. I see no such case where you should interact with this database without a repository layer abstraction. Only the model should have a lifecycle. If you need to use an entity elsewhere, it will introduce coupling and heavily violate the SOLID principles. This defeats the purpose of going through the process of DDD in the first place.

Comment: Hi @RobertHarvey, thanks for the comment! I edited the question and provided further clarification and example code.

Comment: Hey @advayrajhansa, I'm not sure if you understood my question. I added some clarification and example code, to try to explain it specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out eventually.

The problem, as it was stated in the question, was the mapping between layers. I created a mapping interface to declare mapping methods. I used `@ObjectFactory` annotation from MapStruct to deal with generic mapping ([look here](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#object-factories)):

```
public interface EntityMapper<M, E> {
    M toModel(E entity);
    List<M> toModelList(List<E> entities);
    E toEntity(M model);
    List<E> toEntityList(List<M> models);

    // default object factory methods
}
```

Then I proceeded with creating a mapper for each of the child classes and extending it with the EntityMapper interface with concrete types that I want to map.

```
@Mapper(componentModel="spring")
public interface ConcreteEntityMapper extends EntityMapper<ConcreteModelType, ConcreteJpaType> {
}
```

I created an abstract class where I injected the JPA repository and the mapper, and also implemented common methods.

```
abstract class CustomRepositoryImpl<T extends AbstractModelMappedType, E extends AbstractJpaMappedType> {

    private final JpaMappedTypeRepository<E> repository;

    private final EntityMapper<M, E> mapper;

    //... common methods for mapping and querying repositories.
}
```

Then I extended a ConcreteTypeRepositoryImpl with this abstract class, and implemented a generic interface, which I can later use as a reference in other layers.

```
public interface CustomRepository<M> {

    M saveOrUpdate(M model);
    Optional<M> getById(Long id);
    List<M> getByName(String name);
    List<M> getAll();
    void delete(Long id);
}
```

```
@Component
public class ConcreteTypeRepositoryImpl extends CustomRepositoryImpl<ConcreteModelType,ConcreteJpaType> implements CustomRepository<ConcreteModelType> {

    public ConcreteTypeRepositoryImpl(JpaMappedTypeRepository<ConcreteJpaType> repository,
                                  EntityMapper<ConcreteModelType, ConcreteJpaType> mapper) {
        super(repository, mapper);
    }
}
```

And that would be it. Now I can inject CustomRepository into other layers and hit desired repository.